# How can I use system commands in Google Now Voice Actions?

Tags: jailbreak, google

I have an iPhone 4, so making Siri work on it is impossible (you can never find a working port). Is there a Cydia package that can take system commands such as alarm clocks and reminders from Google Now Voice Actions and use them as system commands, like Siri?

Comment: As far as I know, nobody has bothered to make a tweak for this. I got Siri working on an iPod touch 4th generation. You just have to have Spire and either a working Siri proxy server or valid iPhone 4S Siri authentication tokens (daily renewal as well).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will work on iPhone 4 because it does not have Siri but there is a new Jailbreak tweak called [googiri](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/com.mattcmultimedia.googiri/) which allows Google Now to invoke Siri actions. To use Siri actions inside the Google Now app, You can prefix "Siri" keyword before talking. It works well on devices with Siri enabled already.